# Discrete math - the union of empty sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

1. In this problem, we will denote the set of positive integers by N>0 and the set of positive rational numbers by Q>0. Let A, B ⊆ Q>0 be two subsets with the following properties:
   (*) if a ∈ A, then n · a ∈ A for each n ∈ N>0;
   (**) if b ∈ B, then n · b ∈ B for each n ∈ N>0.

Show that if A ∩ B = ∅, then either A = ∅ or B = ∅. 
(1) Suppose that A ≠ ∅. Show that A contains an integer. (Note that the same must be true for B.)
(2) Use proof by contraposition to complete your solution.

Unsure of how to prove the first part of the question, any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: as $A \subset \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$, what do items in $A$ look like? How do we "clear" fractions?

Comment: Suppose that A≠ ∅.  Then there exists at least one a ∈ A.  A⊆ Q>0, therefore each a=q/n, for q,n∈ N. Given (*) if a ∈ A, then n · a ∈ A for each n ∈ N>0.
n * a = n * q/ m = mn*q. 
If m,n and q are rational then their product is rational, therefore A contains at an integer.

Comment: Redo the last sentence. "If $m, n,$ and $q$ are integers then $mnq$ is an integer." The product of three rational numbers need not be an integer.

Comment: ok, thanks, working on part 2, in a formal proof would you need to repeat the proof for the second set?

Comment: What is the title suppose to mean?

Comment: I meant nonempty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part-2
Suppose $A \not = \phi $ then $\exists a \in A$  and a is a rational number, so $a = m/n \ \ m,n \in N$ also for every $i \in N, \ i*a \in A$ so choose $i = n$. Similar proof follows for B

For part-1
Contrapositive is - both $A, B$ are non empty implies $ A \cap B$ is non empty

Proof: since $A$ and $B$ are non empty $\exists a,b \in A,B$ respectively. Since $a,b$ are rational numbers, $a= m_1/n_1,b=m_2/n_2$ so we can choose suitable numbers $m,n$ such that $am = bn$
Hence $A \cap B $ is non empty